# NIST Randomness Tests requires a sequence of ASCII 0's and 1's but does not accept any trial from MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to use NIST randomness test suite for randomness tests of my long 0-1 bit sequences. 
It requires me to supply either the ASCII zeroes and ones or a binary file each byte with 8 bits of data. However, I tried

`save(...,'-ascii')`, `fwrite()` and some other commands to make it work but it does not accept and it gives me a `segmentation error` + `igamc: UNDERFLOW error.`

If anyone can say how to create the exactly matching format it will be really good In addition if anyone knows MATHEMATICA they created their own sample files as below from MATHEMATICA , maybe it can help about the format and you can tell me what to do in MATLAB.

```
BinExp[num_,d_] := Module[{n,L},

If[d > $MaxPrecision, $MaxPrecision = d];

n = N[num,d];

L = First[RealDigits[n,2]]

];

SE = BinExp[E,302500];

Save["data.e",{SE}];
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the test site?

Comment: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html

Could you provide a suggestion for my question?

Comment: FWIW that mathematica code produces an asci file with a mathermatica formatted list expression : `SE={ 1, 0, 1, 0 ... }`

Comment: (line wrapped around 80 cols or so .. ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have the software installed (compiled) as instructed in the [manual](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documents/SP800-22rev1a.pdf)

To see how to run the software start in section 5.3 in the manual.

You can generate an ascii file of random 0/1 generated in matlab as follows:

```
N=10000;  % <-- length of sequence

seq = rand(N,1)>0.5;    
fid=fopen('test.txt','w','native');
fprintf(fid,'%d',seq)
fclose(fid)
```

[Hat tip @Amro who explains the alternate binary file format in comments below.]

Place the file in the program source directory and run

```
> ./assess.exe 10000
```

or equivalent on your system and follow the prompts. Output is in folders within \experiments\AlgorithmTesting\

You can evaluate the program with the test data in folder \data and compare to the results listed in Appendix B, for example here with the ASCII formatted rep of pi in data.pi:

```
> ./assess.exe 1000000 

    0 [data source?]
    .\data\data.pi [path to file?]
    1 [tests?]
    0 [adjust pars?] 
    1 [bitstreams?] 
    0 [ASCII?]
```

**edit**

Here is an (untested) interpretation of Amro's explanation of how to write a string array A of 0/1 as binary:

```
fid=fopen('test.txt','w','native');
fwrite(fid, bin2dec(reshape(num2str(A),[],8)), 'uint8')
fclose(fid)
```

Comment: That is not exactly accurate. The tool expects sequences of 0/1 representing numbers in binary format; for floating points that's [binary fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Fractions). For example `0.625` in base 10 is represented as `0.101` in base 2 (as in: `0*2^0 + 1*2^-1 + 0*2^-2 + 1*2^-3`). And that is what the Mathematica code above is doing. Of course it is evaluating numbers way beyond the numerical machine precision (302500 in the example given), so you're gonna need the Symbolic Math toolbox to do something similar..

Comment: Firstly, thank you Try Hard for your answer, it is really good. Just a small point that ./assess 10000 is the way for running the code.

I have actually still some questions. For example, I could not find any explanation how to check whether the code is working properly. there are really basic testing techniques like giving all ones or all zero-one pattern to check particular tests. However, is there a way to check all the tests at once to say whether we can trust the code?

Comment: For the other commentwhat Amro says is I think true but that is just an example case and I think providing long sequences of ones and zeros is the only necessary point for the randomness tests. I upload the code if somehow you can tell me the file format that will be created with the Save command because when I check their example files there are some blanks and enters in between 25 bit sequences. However, it turned out that you do not need that with fprintf, but still I need a confirmation for this command..

Comment: @Amro you can check one of the sample files, for instance in the data directory of the installation there is a file data.e can be read as uint8. This is not however universally true, some of the other files cannot be read as ascii, they are binary and I did not look into how they are encoded.

Comment: I also checked output for one of the routines run by the program (number of runs) and it's consistent with results with matlab.

Comment: @Onur: from a statistics point of view, are you sure that the distribution of random 0/1 values (generated as: `rand(N,1) > 0.5`) has the same characteristics as the distribution of the binary representation of random values (generated as `BinaryRep(rand(N,1))` assuming we have such a conversion function. I found this [one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5396-conversion-of-fractions-from-binary-to-decimal-and-vice-versa) for MATLAB equivalent to `RealDigits[x,2]` in [MMA](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RealDigits.html))?

Comment: @TryHard ,were you able to find out a way for testing it. I think they have provided the results for their own examples in the manual. However, would it be possible to check the correctness of the results (with some special case analysis) or how to comment on them ?

Comment: @Amro I know that creating random bits and finding binary representation of some random numbers can be different. What I say is that I already created my bits from other sources and I only want to check whether such a bit sequence is random.

Comment: to be honest, I did not download the tool. My comment is based on the Mathematica code you've shown, which is generating binary representation of numbers as I explained...

Comment: @Onur To test then use the provided files as input and check the output in folder \experiments\AlgorithmTesting\

Comment: @Onur, @TryHard: ok I see :) you are using your own sequences of 0/1 already generated elsewhere. So I actually downloaded the thing, and I can now confirm the file representation in `data.e`; it is indeed an ASCII text file containing only the characters `0` or `1` (all whitespace are ignored). The first line when converted from binary representation does evaluate to `E = 2.7183`: `s='101011011111100001010100'; e = sum(2.^(1:-1:-22) .* (s-'0'))`

Comment: @TryHard: here is the relevant source code used to read the binary-formatted files (extracted from `src/utilities.c`): http://pastebin.com/mVYq9Wt3 (As they say, the code is the best source of documentation). So I think the binary representation packs the 0/1 from ASCII representation into the bits of bytes. That is each sequence of 8 0/1 values are written as the integer they represent in binary. So the previous line I mentioned would be written as: `fwrite(fid, bin2dec(['10101101';'11111000';'01010100']), '*uint8')`

Comment: Ran some of the tests individually with data.pi and compared output to the results in Appendix B... looks ok.

Comment: @TryHard I tried some special cases and the results also seem ok and as you said only way to ensure is to check the code and the theory behind it.

Comment: @TryHard I have another question about NIST with the title "NIST Randomness Test fails in rand function (of MATLAB) generated bits", if it is possible in anyway maybe we can discuss it there, too. Thanks.

Comment: @Onur Ok, I can try to answer if you have a question :)